# Unity 3D экспорт и импорт

Tags: c#, unity3d, файлы, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Как реализовать опцию `открыть с помощью` > `игра на Юнити`, и чтобы код получил необходимый файл. Чтобы работало с мобильных устройств.

Если эта задумка бредовая, то, как можно организовать ***редактор уровней*** с ***импортом*** и ***экспортом*** уровней этих самых (желательно через *файл*, либо какой-то *текст* (*json*, *XML*, и т.д.))?

Возможно, это можно как-то организовать открытие этих файлов в самом приложении?

Comment: Это все равно что ездить на велосипеде и готовить. Вроде бы и что-то новое, но не то... Зачем на платформе android редактировать уровни?

Comment: Много возни, проще в самом приложении выбирать файл.

Comment: И как можно в самом приложении выбирать файл?

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял, что ты именно хочешь, но в `c#`, как и во всех нормальных языках, есть функция открывать файлы. Если вопрос на тему как хранить это в файле, используй формат `JSON`. В `Unity` есть интерфейс, привяжи к кнопкам код, который открывает файл. Надеюсь, помог. Если помог, отметь этот ответ как лучший:)

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду, чтобы можно было воспользоваться функцией "открыть с помощью" и приложение выбрать. Как она устроена?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: -projectPath аргумент командной строки?

Comment: я лично не разбираюсь в командной строке, но все штуки с `-` это метки. к примеру `-r`

Comment: Но через эту штуку можно будет реализовать логику открытия файлов через "открыть с помощью"?

Comment: я думаю нет, юнити не предназначен для этого. только если получишь доступ к параметрам функции main() тогда можно будет прочитать параметры